# Prove a square free word

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

A square free word is a word that does not contain any subword twice in a row. 
An infinite word is defined:
$$
w_i=\{ \textrm{the maximal natural j that } 2^j \textrm{ devides } i\}
$$
the first "letters" are:
$$w=01020103...$$
how can I prove $w$ is a square-free word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Consider the following operation on any word, finite or infinite, over $\Bbb N$: if $x$ is such a word, $\hat x$ is obtained by omitting the $0$ letters and subtracting $1$ from each letter that remains. Thus, if $x=01020103$, for instance, $\hat x=0102$.

- Show that $\hat w=w$.

Suppose that $x\in\Bbb N^*$, and $xx$ is a subword of $w$.

- Show that $\hat x\hat x$ is a subword of $w$, and that $|\hat x\hat x|=\frac12|xx|$. Use this to derive a contradiction.

Comment: not sure I follow. why $\hat{x}\hat{x}$ is a subword?

Comment: @user107761: Have you tried calculating the beginning of $\hat w$ to see how the operation behaves? I really hesitate to say much more, because both statements are quite straightforward, but here’s a further observation: the operation is basically just dropping out the odd-numbered terms and dividing each of the even-numbered indices by $2$.

Comment: yes yes. I've noticed it a minute after sending the comment... now I'm trying to figure hot the second part

Comment: just to be sure, the contradiction is that I have 00 in w?

Comment: @user107761: Yes, that’s one way to do it. Another is to start by assuming that $x$ is a *shortest* subword such that $xx$ is a subword of $w$.

Comment: and to say that either $|\hat{x}|$ is odd, else, I use the sae operator again and again until $|\hat{\hat{\hat{x}}}|$ is odd. am I correct?

Comment: @user107761: That would be a third legitimate argument. The simplest, I think, is the one in my previous comment: $\hat x$ is shorter than $x$, so if $x$ is assumed to be as short as possible such that $xx$ is a subword of $w$, $\hat x$ gives you an immediate contradiction.